# App Engine high latency

Tags: latency, google-app-engine

Hi we have an static web page using Smarty, we want to migrate it from our private web server on Compute Engine to App Engine.

We did made the migration but on App Engine we got a latency of 3 sec to load the pague and on the server on Compute Engine is 84 Ms

Same App different server, how can we eliminate the high latency (TTFB)?, thank you.

Comment: You're going to have to do some profiling with something like Xdebug or Blackfire.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hosting a Static web page, you could take a different approach and host it on Cloud Storage, this is totally supported by google. You can follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

If you want to host it on App  engine, check the type of instance you have configured, it maybe too small, you could try a bigger [instance type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes), and also check if you have auto scale enable, maybe you are running out of resources, which the compute engine instance did provide. Also take a look to this [GCP blog post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/08/How-to-Troubleshoot-Latency-in-Your-App-Engine-Application.html) and see if you can help you troubleshoot.

Also you could take a look into you .yaml file, and make use of “options default_expiration” or the “expiration” elements. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref)

If you're App engine is a standard environment you can server files from another GCP product or from  CDN. [Here is some info](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref).

All the code related docs are on python but you can change it yo many other runtimes in the top right corner of the page

Hope it's usefull.